# facebook api " syntax error, unexpected 'use' "

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Hello I am trying to use the facebook api to verify a access token and get the user data like email etc..

However when I test it I get this `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)`.

Here is the code I am using currently.

```
        require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
        require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
        require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
        require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
        require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
        require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
        require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
        require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );


        use Facebook\FacebookSession;
        use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
        use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
        use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
        use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
        use Facebook\GraphObject;
        use Facebook\GraphUser;


        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('My App ID', 'My Secret');

        //   Use one of the helper classes to get a FacebookSession object.
        //   FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
        //   FacebookCanvasLoginHelper
        //   FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper
        // or create a FacebookSession with a valid access token:
        $session = new FacebookSession('My Access Token');

        try {
            $me = (new FacebookRequest(
                $session, 'GET', '/me'
            ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
            echo $me->getName();
        } catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
            // The Graph API returned an error
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Some other error occurred
        }
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this error? I never used "use" before and I have read the php documentation for it but i still can't figure it out.

Comment: remove the single quote after FacebookSession and FAcebookRedirectLoginHelper

Comment: it still does not work even after removing them, it still says 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /home/username/public_html/application/models/login_model.php on line 95  and line 95 is use Facebook\FacebookSession;

Comment: What version of PHP are you running on the machine that is executing this code? Also, you have `use Facebook\FacebookSession;` in there twice.

Comment: Is this code from within a function? You can't use `use` within one.

Comment: Your new code, with the quotes removed, has no syntax errors, according to my pasting it into a file and running `php -l` over it. Are you absolutely sure you're running the new version? Also, if line 95 is `use Facebook\FacebookSession`, what happened to the 94 lines before it? We can't guess at what might be causing syntax errors in code you've not posted.

Comment: yeah it is in a function I will test it outside a function and the php version is 5.4, also I removed the second use Facebook\FacebookSession;

Comment: @Wes As Matt Gibson said, you cannot put `use` statements inside a function. That will cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: Put your "use" at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well thanks everybody I finally got it working, turns out you have to make sure that the code below is not within a function like ceejayoz said. I just moved it outside my code igniter model class and now it works, thanks.

```
//We need to load the Facebook api library
require_once( getcwd().'/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php' );
require_once( getcwd().'/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( getcwd().'/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( getcwd().'/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( getcwd().'/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( getcwd().'/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

//Setup the facebook api for Facebook Validate
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
```

Answer (score 2):

These lines are invalid

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession';
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper';
```

Correct is:

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. Put your `use` statements outside `{ }`.

For example, the following is incorrect:

```
<?php
if($_GET["page"]=="index.php"){
        use Facebook\FacebookSession;
}
?>
```

The following is correct:

```
<?php
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
if($_GET["page"]=="index.php"){
   ...
}
?>
```